# Error when translating a query to a field of type "inet" in postgreSql via linq and EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have an Entity class that contains a property Ipaddr of type `IPAddress`. It is stored in the postgresql database in a field of type `inet`, as intended. To search by part of a substring I use a method like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Switch>> GetSwitches(string? searchIpaddr, string? searchSysname)
{
           var switches = context.Switches.Include(s => s.Network) as IQueryable<Switch>;

           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchSysname))
            {
              searchSysname = searchSysname.Trim();
              switches = switches.Where(s => EF.Functions.ILike(s.Sysname, $"%{searchSysname}%"));
            }


           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchIpaddr))
            {
              searchIpaddr = searchIpaddr.Trim();
              switches = switches.Where(s => EF.Functions.ILike(s.Ipaddr.ToString(), $"%{searchIpaddr}%"));
            }
        
            return await switches.ToListAsync(); 
            

}
```

For string property `Sysname` it works, but for `Ipaddr` an error occurs

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet() .Where(s => s.Ipaddr.ToString() == __ip_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Please tell me how to rewrite the code so that Linq can broadcast a query to the database. I don’t want to get the entire collection and then filter it on the client side, since there can be a lot of data.

Comment: The simple solution is to change your mapped properties to use `Byte[]` instead of `IPAddress` (but you can still use `IPAddress` in a computed property). If you really want to use `IPAddress` as a low-level domain-model data-type (...which is silly, imo) you'll need to write a type-converter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: @Dai In documentation [link](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html) a .Net type for inet postgres type is IPAddress. 
I tried to use converter like this, but it does not work `public class IPAddressToStringConverter : ValueConverter<IPAddress, string>
{
    public IPAddressToStringConverter(ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null)
        : base(
              ip => ip.ToString(),
              str => IPAddress.Parse(str),
              mappingHints)
    {
    }
}`

Comment: The .NET type support you're looking at seems to only apply to direct use of Postgres' ADO.NET provider types (i.e. `NpgsqlCommand` and `NpgsqlDataReader` - but not EFCore, which has its own restrictions on what types you can use.

Comment: @Dai Code `modelBuilder.Entity<Switch>(e => {e.Property(p => p.Ipaddr)                  .HasColumnType("inet"); });` works well. And this method `public async Task<Switch?> GetSwitch(string ip) { return await context.Switches.Where(s => s.Ipaddr == IPAddress.Parse(ip) ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();}` returns data.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I tried using EF.Functions.Abbreviate(s.Ipaddr) instead of s.Ipaddr.ToString(). An error is the same.

Comment: Can you please open an issue on https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg with a minimal, runnable code sample that shows the error happening? It will probably take me a while to get around to investgating, but I'll do my best.